# Package access not enforced at runtime?

Tags: java, jvm, package, javac

I am facing a legacy application that needs to run on a very old system (Java 1.4). I need to override a protected method (GridBagLayout.GetLayoutInfo) which returns a GridBagLayoutInfo object. The problem is that the GridBagLayoutInfo class itself was package-private until Java 1.6 (then it was made public).

So let's take this code:

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagLayoutInfo;

public class GridBagLayoutSubclass extends GridBagLayout
{
    protected GridBagLayoutInfo GetLayoutInfo(Container parent, int sizeflag)
    {
        System.out.println("Foo");
        return super.GetLayoutInfo(parent, PREFERREDSIZE);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        (new GridBagLayoutSubclass()).GetLayoutInfo(new Container(), 1);
    }
}
```

I can compile this on a "modern" Java system. What surprises me is that the generated class files work on the target Java system (Java 1.4) even though the GridBagLayoutInfo class is package-private in that runtime environment. Why is this the case? Doesn't the JVM check visibility of types at runtime?

Comment: Hhm. Wouldn't running code compiled with Java [anything > 4] fail to run at all when executed on a Java 4 runtime? Are you sure the target system really *is* executing with Java 4?

Comment: @Mena: Depends on the target release level you specify (`javac`'s `-target` option).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ah yes, fair point.

Comment: Byte code verification has been mostly absent in earlier JRE releases from Sun, I remember it was possible to get around some language definitions like directly accessing foreign private fields or being able to run a private main method in Java 1.3. Its quite possible your target platform simply doesn't check for correct inheritance. Its not defined behavior, just an implementation quirk.

Comment: This has nothing to do with sloppy verifiers; the same pattern works with up-to-date JVMs too. Afaik, method signatures are not subject to accessibility checks. Note that the *invocation* `super.GetLayoutInfo(parent, PREFERREDSIZE)` is even accepted at source code level, even when its return type `GridBagLayoutInfo` is not accessible. It’s only the declaration of the overriding method which is not accepted. Putting the invocation into a different method having a formal return type of `Object` would allow compiling it without objections.

Comment: @Holger Yes but my question is -- once this has been compiled (on a modern Java system), why does the overriden GetLayoutInfo method run without issues on the target Java 1.4 system, where the GridBagLayoutInfo class is not accessible?

Comment: Well, that’s exactly what I tried to explain, *method signatures are not subject to accessibility checks*, even on today’s JVMs. In your code example, you’re not accessing that type in any other way.

Comment: @Holger Do you have an official reference for that (JLS for example) ?

Comment: It’s hard to point to an absent place (i.e. if there’s no place telling that this should be rejected). I’ll try to gather the parts that allow the conclusion that this is an intentional omission, however, that will take some time.

Comment: Even Java 9, where accessibility at runtime will be taken much more seriously, will (unfortunately!) not prevent what I call an "API leak". See the recent discussion around http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jigsaw-dev/2017-May/012437.html (look at the last paragraph).